# Use variable declare in inner methods

Tags: java, variables

I have two `ItemListener`s which have inner methods that declare a variable for each. I want to compare the two variable in the upperClass.

This is my Code:

```
public class MyFrame extends JFrame {

public MyFrame () { 
    initialize();
}

public void initialize() {
    this.setSize(600,200);
    this.setTitle("Frame");
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    String [] brothers = {"John", "Francis"};
    String [] sisters = {"Sarah","Diana"};

    JPanel centralPnl = new JPanel();
    this.getContentPane().add(centralPnl, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    final JComboBox broBox = new JComboBox(brothers);
    centralPnl.add(broBox);

    final JComboBox sisBox = new JComboBox(sisters);
    centralPnl.add(sisBox);

    broBox.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
        @Override
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
            if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED)  {
                 String selectedValue = broBox.getSelectedItem().toString();

                //connection to DB to get data; DBConnection is a class that connects to DB
                //and a have getAge method which returns age of brothers in array format
                String[] age = new DBConnection().getAge(selectedValue);                    
                String johnAge = String[0];
            }
        }
    });

    sisBox.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
        @Override
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {

            if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
                String selectedValue = broBox.getSelectedItem().toString();

                //connection to DB to get data; DBConnection is a class that connects to DB
                //and a have getAge method which returns age of sisters in array format
                String[] age = new DBConnection().getAge(selectedValue);                    

                String sarahAge = String[0]
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I'd like to compare `johnAge` and `sarahAge`. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare `johnAge` and `sarahAge` more broadly. For example, define the variables, but don't initialize them, in the outer class. You could also make them instance variables instead of method-local variables.

```
public class MyFrame extends JFrame {

    String johnAge;
    String sarahAge;


    public void initialize() {

    ....


    //Item listener {
        johnAge = "whatever";
    }

    //Item listener 2 {
        sarahAge = "whatever";
    }

    ....

    //You have access to them now indefinitely through this class's instance

}

}
```

I'd recommend reading up on [scope](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/scope.html) in Java, since this is a really common coding problem.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've tried, but firstly it is me asked to change modifier to `final`; once this done, there is another error:

`"The final local variable cannot be assigned, since it is defined in an enclosing type"`

Comment: I made a sort of silly mistake. You actually need to declare the variables at class level. Only final local variables can be accessed by anonymous inner classes. I'm updating the code right now to show what I mean. Sorry for the mistake, I don't have my work comp with me right now.

Comment: Don't worry, I only appreciate your try to help me

Comment: have you update your code? I see "edited 20 mins ago" but the code is the same. Something's wrong?

Comment: I did update my code. Notice now that the variables are declared at class level. I added a class to my code example just like your class and declared the variables as instance variables therein.

Comment: Ok, Thank you very much. Sorry for my mistake, where I'm from these are small hours!

Comment: @Bernheart No problem, glad I could help. No apology needed, good luck